# Different behavior of '\0' in Character Array and String

Tags: c++

I have a character array and string. Both array and string belong to the same object.

```
char str[]="Hello";
string s="Hello";
```

I assume to set a null character at a specific index.

```
str[2]='\0';
s[2]='\0';
```

The Resulting `str` and `s` returned the below snippet where the character array `str` is slicing from index 2 and removed after that but on the contrary, String `s` only slice and remove index 2.

```
He
Helo
```

Why these are showing different behavior

Comment: probably string simply write `string.length()` number of char to output and the terminal simply only not show the `'\0'`;

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: The character with code zero is a null character, not a null pointer.

Comment: The text you present is a result of some processing, eg. sending data to some output stream (possibly the standard `cout`) with some functions (probably the standard overloaded operator `<<`) while the stream was connected to some output device (assume the text console). So the results depend on an actual realisation of all three statements in parentheses - but you said nothing about them. Without that info the best guess is that the `<<` operator is defined differently for argument of type `char*` than for `string`.

Answer (score 2):

A char array, that has the escape character `\0` in it, acts as a C string. The escape character indicated that that is where the string ends, and therefore that's all that's printed when printing the char array. In a c++ string, on the other end, the escape character acts like any other character. the ascii value of `\0` is NUL, and as the name suggests, it's just - nothing. So, when printing the string, the character that is NUL is just ignored.
See
[this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_strings.htm) for more about the subject.

Comment: The character with value zero is a null character, not an escape character. An escape character is one that “escapes” the normal interpretation of a string, such as how the backslash in `"abc\adef"` changes from the normal interpretation (each character in the source code is part of the string) to something else (the character after the backslash is interpreted in a special way). The `\0` itself is an escape sequence, but the character that results from it is just a null character. Also NULL is a macro for a null pointer constant; a character with code zero is just plain null, not NULL.

Comment: NUL is an accepted way of representing ascii code 0.

Comment: NUL is an ASCII character with code zero. Technically that is not the same as C’s meaning of null character, as C does not require ASCII. Regardless, “NUL” is different from “NULL”, so “NULL” is still not a good description of the null character.

Comment: that's noted, and i've edited that already

Comment: Interesting,  so when s[2] is ran, it inserts null into index 2, therefore when the object is read, it says helo? or he lo

Comment: helo, since null is null, not space. space has an ascii value of 32

Comment: Exactly what is printed when the program sends a null to a terminal depends on the terminal software. I've seen terminals that ignore, terminals that print question marks, terminals that print boxes or other special sigils, terminals that print funky hex dumps, and probably a few others I've forgotten.

Comment: true. I've seen squares with zeroes in them quite often.

Comment: "*A char array, that has the escape character \0 in it, acts as a C string*" - to be accurate, the array itself doesn't act like anything, it is just memory storage. How it is processed determines the behavior. `cout.operator<<(char*)` expects the `char*` to be null-terminated. But you can get the same output behavior with a `char[]` as you get with a `string` if you use `cout.write()` instead, eg: `cout.write(str, 5)` will print `Helo` when `str` is set to `"Hello"` and then `str[2]` is set to `'\0'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/ODF93Y)).